# Setting Image on tags

Tags: discussion, support, edits, tag-wiki

I have seen several tags of stack overflow have image on that like android, facebook etc. And I want to add image on  some other tags as well. Can I do that? If yes, then how? If no then who can do that?

Comment: Those are sponsored tags.

Comment: amm hmm, okay, that means I can't haan.. :(

Comment: Thanks @AlEverett, that detailes every thing? :)